# CSS Content element use :before img works weird

Tags: html, css, element

I'm trying to place three different images before some li points, but somehow, it just don't work the way I want. Can someone help me? 
Right now, it looks like this: [CSS content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjBg9.png)

As you can see, the images don't stay next to the text I want to, even though I used :before. The images are also very big, but I just want them just as small as the text.

This is the CSS code I've used:

```
a[href*="bron.pdf"]:before {
    content: url("PDF%20img%20.gif");
}

a[href*="bron.vcf"]:before {
content: url("vcard-icon.png");
}

a[href*="bron.jpg"]:before {
content: url("adobe%20img%20.png");
}
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<section>
   <h4>Downloads</h4>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="bron.pdf" data kb="1267">project_CMDA_Moet_ik_rennen.pdf</a> (1.3MB)</li>
           <li><a href="bron.vcf">Contactgegevens_CMDA_Moet_ik_rennen.vcf</a></li>
          <li><a href="bron.jpg" data-kb="569">Poster_CMDA_Moet_ik_rennen.jpg</a> (569KB)</li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to manage it will be to set a background-image in place of an image to be able to change height and width of the image. Also use `display: inline-block` to have the text and the image next to each other.

```
a:before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px; 
    height: 18px;
    background-size: cover;   
}
```

(Of course, adjust the height and the width depends of the size you want).

And then add the background-image property to each of your element

```
a[href*="bron.pdf"]:before {
    background-image: url("PDF%20img%20.gif");
}

a[href*="bron.vcf"]:before {
    background-image: url("vcard-icon.png");
}

a[href*="bron.jpg"]:before {
    background-image: url("adobe%20img%20.png");
}
```

[Here an exemple of a working exemple](https://fiddle.jshell.net/owcvtvyb/)

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to set the answer as best answer for the next people comes here :)

Answer (score 0):

You must set a `height` and `width` for them of how big you want them to be. Also try using: `display:inline` for the images and the text container (if it is a p tag or any tag) or if this doesn't work out, use `float:left` for the images.

Comment: Not sure that he can change the height and width of an image in pseudo element